# "ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid"

Tags: kernel, source, realtime

I have been stuck on this issue for two days now and couldnt find a fix for this. I installed a realtime kernel with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-rt
```

because [KauNet](http://www.kau.se/en/kaunet) (which is an ipfw extension) requires a real-time kernel for millisecond granularity.

However after trying to install KauNet I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
include/linux/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing
Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
```

Both files are there. `auto.conf`can be found in `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.31-10-rt/include/config` and `autoconf.h` is in `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.31-10-rt/include/linux`.

Before I installed `2.6.31-10-rt` kernel i was on `2.6.32-21-generic` and KauNet/ipfw was working.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: A little late, but maybe you can reconstruct in case you have solved the issue in the meantime: Is `kernel-package` installed?

Comment: After all I have solved the issue. I can't recall how I did it though. It was quite a while ago I am afraid.