# Kernel configuration is invalid error while trying to install paragon ufsd professional drivers for HFS+

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, dkms

### short question:

While running the install.sh Skript for Paragon UFSD drivers I get the Error message:

```
 ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid."; 
\include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing."$
 Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
```

How can I run "make oldconfig && make prepare" and does that make sense?

### Disclaimer:

I know this question was asked in context of NVIDIA driver, but it was answered by suggesting other ways to install NVIDIA not telling how to run the make command ([Installing NVIDIA Driver: Error Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751655/installing-nvidia-driver-error-run-make-oldconfig-make-prepare-on-kernel-s?s=1|2.5783)). In another question the problem was solved but the person who asked can not remember how (["ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461217/error-kernel-configuration-is-invalid)).

### Context for my question:

I am trying now for several days to install the Paragon-147-PRE_NTFS_Linux_9.4_Pro UFSD drivers for full read&write NTFS and HFS+ filesystem support. The drivers officially support Ubuntu 16.04LTS.
After crunching my old Linux installation I use a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.2LTS (downloaded from the UBUNTU website) with nothing but the standard installation, though I run it on a triple boot system (Windows7, elementary, Ubuntu) if that matters.

I installed the build-essentials, dkms and linux-headers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo install dkms
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic
uname -a
Linux notebook 4.8.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 15:06:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As far as I know I match all requirements (hardware and installed software) listed in the paragon manual (http://download.paragon-software.com/doc/ntfs_hfs_linux_9_4_user_manual.pdf):

```
»build-essential« ist bereits die neuste Version (12.1ubuntu2).
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
GNU Make 4.1
Gebaut für x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
kmod version 22
-XZ -ZLIB -EXPERIMENTAL
dkms: 2.2.0.3
```

I unpacked the Paragon driver package and started the install.sh skript (note on the "out of range" warning: I previously tried it on 4.4. kernel without that warning but the same final error message):

```
viejo@notebook:/usr/tmp/ufsd/Paragon-147-PRE_NTFS_Linux_9.4_Pro$ sudo ./install.sh
By installing this software you accept the terms of End User License Agreement listed in License file.
Continue installing? [yes/no/read].
yes
Current kernel version is out of supported range. Proceed at your own risk? [yes/No]
yes
Searching and removing previously installed UFSD driver in /lib/modules/4.8.0-39-generic/
Would you like to mount NTFS/HFS+ volumes with UFSD driver automatically? [yes/no]
yes
Automount configured
Would you like UFSD driver to rebuild after kernel updates? [yes/no]
yes
Setting DKMS configuration
Preparing to install
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for paragon-ufsd: head not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/paragon-ufsd/head/build/make.log for more information.
Can't prepare driver configuration
cat: /var/lib/dkms/paragon-ufsd/head/4.8.0-39-generic/x86_64/log/make.log: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

In the make.log I found this error message:

```
...
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic“ wird betreten
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing."$
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
...
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic/scripts/Makefile.build:289: die Regel für Ziel „/$
make[3]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/paragon-ufsd/head/build/ifslinux/ufsdjnl.o] Fehler 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic/Makefile:1491: die Regel für Ziel „_module_/var/l$
make[2]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/paragon-ufsd/head/build] Fehler 2
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic“ wird verlassen
Makefile:150: die Regel für Ziel „sub-make“ scheiterte
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic“ wird verlassen
Makefile:94: die Regel für Ziel „ufsd.ko“ scheiterte
make: *** [ufsd.ko] Fehler 2
```

when looking for the source-code files and the config-file as suggested in the Paragon Manual troubleshooting it seems to me, that I have everything needed:

```
viejo@notebook:/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic$ ls
arch    Documentation  include  Kconfig   mm              scripts   tools   zfs
block   drivers        init     kernel    Module.symvers  security  ubuntu
certs   firmware       ipc      lib       net             sound     usr
crypto  fs             Kbuild   Makefile  samples         spl       virt

viejo@notebook:/boot$ ls
abi-4.4.0-64-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-4.8.0-36-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-4.8.0-39-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-4.4.0-64-generic      System.map-4.4.0-64-generic
config-4.8.0-36-generic      System.map-4.8.0-36-generic
config-4.8.0-39-generic      System.map-4.8.0-39-generic
efi                          vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
grub                         vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic  vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic  vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic
initrd.img-4.8.0-39-generic  vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic.efi.signed
```

I do not know how to proceed. I would be greatful for any help or hint where I can get more information.

Olaf

Comment: I want to point out a link https://stackoverflow.com/a/67156634/14346786

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to share how I solved my problem regarding the installation of Paragon Professional UFSD drivers for HFS+ and NTFS in case anybody else run into similar problems.

I created a support Ticket at Paragon and got a new build that supports Ubuntu 16.4.2lts with 4.8 kernel.

No need to run make oldconfig etc...

But be aware, you still need to install the build-essentials, dkms and source code (headers):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic
```

good luck
Olaf

Answer (score 5):

Reinstall Linux Headers or copy the file

```bsh
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

```bsh
sudo cp /usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-43-generic/include/generated/autoconf.h /usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-44-generic/include/generated/
```

```bsh
sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential
sudo apt install --reinstall dkms
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-signed-generic
```

Comment: For me, reinstalling the headers package helped (and there was no need for copying the header file). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've upgraded Ubuntu from 19.04 to 19.10. Yesterday I realized that the Paragon-ufsd_driver_Retail_APFS_lke_9.6.10 driver that worked great on ubuntu 19.04,on the 19.10 (kernel 5.3.0-21-generic) does not work anymore. At this point,I tried to reinstall it,like this :

root@ziomario-Z390-AORUS-PRO:/home/ziomario/Scaricati/Paragon-ufsd_driver_Retail_APFS_lke_9.6.10# ./install.sh

By installing this software you accept the terms of End User License Agreement listed in License file.

Continue installing? [yes/no/read].

yes

Current kernel version is out of supported range. Proceed at your own risk? [Yes/no]

yes

Searching and removing previously installed UFSD driver in /lib/modules/5.3.0-21-generic/

Would you like UFSD driver to rebuild after kernel updates? [yes/no]
yes

Setting DKMS configuration

Preparing to install

ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for paragon-uapfs: head not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-21-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/paragon-uapfs/head/build/make.log for more information.
Error: Can't prepare driver configuration

let's give a look at the make.log file :

echo >&2 " ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid."; \

echo >&2 " include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\

echo >&2 " Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it."; \

echo >&2 ; \

/bin/false)

I think that the Antonios Petriccas patches could help me,but his repo does not work anymore ! If u try to open the link you will get a nice error 404.