# "Make" error - DIGImend Kernel install for drawing tablet

Tags: drivers, bash, make, zip, graphics-tablet

Okay, after helpful comments (below), I got further down the road after installing flex and then got same error w/ Bison, so I installed that.

Now I'm getting this:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop. make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:213: archheaders] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-39-generic' make: *** [Makefile:22: modules] Error 2
```

I'm guessing that 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl' or similar is not there?

Per comments below, I ran 'uname -a' and got this:

```
Linux radeoflier-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-CMT 5.15.0-40-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 15 12:54:21 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

OLD___
**ONCE I GOT PAST PERMISSIONS (sudo make)...**

I believe that this *might be the real issue, (but again, novice, so...):

```
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
```

I've found several posts on 'askubuntu' related to this but none of those solutions seem to solve my error.
[Kernel configuration is invalid error while trying to install paragon ufsd professional drivers for HFS+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890712/kernel-configuration-is-invalid-error-while-trying-to-install-paragon-ufsd-profe)

**BACKGROUND / PREVIOUS INQUIRY**
I'm trying to follow instructions (here: https://github.com/beyond-1234/digimend-kernel-drivers-spbnick) to install a patch(?) from the same team (ZIP at the bottom: https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/issues/87).

**FYI** this worked in Ubuntu 18.*

When I run "make" from the unzipped dir, I get a bunch of these errors:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_32991’: Permission denied
```

and it ends with this:

```
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Makefile:635: syncconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:745: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-51-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:22: modules] Error 2
```

**OLD:** *I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 - it's a fresh install with only a few apps.*

**EDIT-UPDATE:** I downloaded from *Ubuntu 22.04.3* and installed yesterday. Here's a full run of the error which is still happening - are the headers still incorrect? I am willing to RTFM, but just not sure where to go to get started understanding this stuff. Thanks for any help pointing me in right direction!

**FIXED PERMISSION ERROR, here's new error:** ran "make" as "sudo make", new error code below - where can I find documentation on these errors?

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-39-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/radeoflier/Desktop/DIGImend_Drivers/digimend-kernel-drivers-support_uc-logic_artisul_d13 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-39-generic'
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/confdata.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/expr.o
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Makefile:622: syncconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:735: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-39-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:22: modules] Error 2
```

-- many thanks to Ubuntu vets, "Ask Ubuntu..." has been enormously helpful getting me started --

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: If it's a *fresh install*, why did you install an EOL release. Your upgrade path is also well gone, as it upgraded to [21.04 but even that disappeared when it went EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/) so *fresh* installing a long-EOL release makes little sense to me.

Comment: Do note one part of your paste shows a 5.13 kernel; where 20.10 used the older 5.8 kernel..   If you're on the 2021-October release (21.10) I'd suggest starting with 22.04 given [21.10 EOL warnings are out](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/)

Comment: I installed 22.04 yesterday - I had been on 18.xx and it asked me to upgrade (I'm sure it was just old and I'm novice and didn't understand).

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found` probably means that you need to install `flex`. Try `sudo apt install flex`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose. Is `x86` your architecture? Show in your question the output of `uname -a`.

Comment: Sorry for bad etiquette!
What I'm learning from these comments has GREATLY helped my capacity to search for solutions on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to answer, yes it's x86 (also in `unmae -a` realit above)